# Nano Problems with History Files

Tags: nano

When I am editing a yml file with Nano I see this red error Problems with history file. Once I'm done I get the error below. I'm still learning linux and have a basic understanding of commands, but I followed the path /home/[my username]/.local/share and did not see a nano folder so I created one. It still does not work??? I'm assuming /home/[my username] is my root path when I do su to login to root?

root@debian:/home/docker# nano docker-compose.yml
Unable to create directory /root/.local/share/nano/: No such file or directory
It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions.